# Should I put /boot on SSD or HDD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, cache, enhanceio

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 64bit. I am planning to implement EnhanceIO to use my new 25GB SSD drive for caching my 4TB RAID 0 array. The raid array is partitioned as: 500MB /boot, 20GB /, 200GB /vmware, and 3.4TB /home.
I understand there are issues/complexity with caching root partitions, so I'm thinking of making a 500MB /boot partion on the SSD.
My question, will it make a difference putting /boot on the SSD? 
This system is on 24/7, and really only gets rebooted once every few months. I'm thinking the kernel is the only thing getting loaded from the /boot partition, and it likely will stay entirely in memory. So having the /boot on SSD won't make any difference on a running system. Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/boot is only used on booting the linux (or updating it's boot files). Caching it will not give *any* performance improvement if your computer is not rebooted.

Consider using fast drive as swap partition